# Install resources with code in luarocks

Tags: lua, luarocks

I need to embed resources (html templates) within a lua rock, as they are required by the program. But i cannot find where to describe them in the configuration.

Trying to put them in `build.install.con` key (as below) does not work, because the files are then stored in a "flat" manner, losing the directories.

```
{
  package = "...",
  version = "master-1",
  source = { ... },
  description = { ... },
  dependencies = { ... },
  build = {
    type    = "builtin",
    modules = { ... },
    install = {
      bin = { ...},
      conf = { RESOURCES },
    },
  },
}
```

Is there a way to specify resources? And where are they installed if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `build.copy_directories` directive (see [here](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Rockspec-format)), which is an array of directory names that shall be copied from the source directory into the rocks tree.

You might also be interested in the [datafile](https://github.com/hishamhm/datafile) module, which helps with loading resources from various locations (including a rocks tree).